# rotating a fixed-width rectangle to opposite corners

Tags: geometry

I need to draw a rotated rectangle in AutoCAD. This rectangle has a fixed width of 3-1/2" and an unknown length. Assuming that the lower left corner is at (0,0), I know that the top right corner is at (1'5-1/8",0'6-5/32"). How do I determine the angle of rotaion?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You have the length of the diagonal (since you have opposite points)

Also you have the width, figure out the length and then you can find the angle of rotation using right angle triangles (better draw a figure).

Comment: You are correct. Can't believe I didn't see that. Thx.